# How to read csv file lines and split elements in line into list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have csv file. When I open it by VisualStudio, i have something like this:

```
nr1  nr2  nr3  name  place
10  01  02  Jack  New York
10  01  03  David  London
10  02  01  Jasmine  New Jersey
```

There are two spaces between elements in every line and one space in name of the place.

When I open csv file by Excel, there are just elements in every other column.

I don't know how can I read this csv file to make every line a list of elements like this:

```
my_list = [

['10','01','02','Jack','New York']
['10','01','03','David','London']
['10','02','01','Jasmine','New Jersey']]
```

Cause I want to make some loop after this:

```
for line in my_list:
     nr1 = line[0]
     nr2 = line[1]
     nr3 = line[2]
     name = line[3]
     place = line[4]
```

And here I will make an instance of the class for every line.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [tab delimited csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) file. Meaning that each column is separated by tab ('\t').

The following code should work. 
**Updated**: use [.rstrip()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm) to remove `\n`

```
import csv

f = open('data.csv')

data = []
for line in f:
    data_line = line.rstrip().split('\t')
    data.append(data_line)

print data
```

Comment: It worked, but in every list in last element there is 'place\n' -> "\n" sign. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: rstrip() to remove space, tab, enter, on the left, or strip() for both size

Answer (score 3):

Try this, using the csv module and its `reader()` method:

```
import csv

f = open('file.csv')

the_data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter r'\t'))[1:]
```

Comment: `with open` is better.

Comment: I tried:
with open("file_name.csv", 'r') as f:
            the_data = list(csv.reader(f))[:1]
            print(the_data)

and it prints:
[['nr1\tnr2\tnr3\tname\tplace']]

Answer (score 1):

Using the `csv` module makes doing it fairly easy. The only trick was to make the two-letter delimiter used in the input file appear to be a single character, `','`, in the example, because it the default.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

with open('my_data.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(line.replace('  ', ',') for line in csv_file)
    my_list = list(reader)
    pprint(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[['nr1', 'nr2', 'nr3', 'name', 'place'],
 ['10', '01', '02', 'Jack', 'New York'],
 ['10', '01', '03', 'David', 'London'],
 ['10', '02', '01', 'Jasmine', 'New Jersey']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open("file.csv","r") as file:
   data = file.read()

data = data.strip(' ').split('\n')

for i in len(data):
   data[i] = data[i].strip(' ').split(',')
   for j in len(data[i]):
      data[i][j] = data[i][j].strip(' ')
print (data)
```