# convert .txt values to lists in a Python script

Tags: python

Imagine we have a .txt file named a.txt and it has below lines.

```
1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3,0
20, 30, 40, 20, 35, 34,0
Oct1,Nov1,Dec1
```

now we have a python project where I am going to read above line and assign different lines in different 
variables in a list format.

ex: I need to assign as below

```
var1=[1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3,0]
var2=[20, 30, 40, 20, 35, 34,0]
var3=["Oct1","Nov1","Dec1"]
```

Could you help me on how to do this in python

Comment: Do you know how to read the file? Do you know how to take a string and split it up into the list items? Do you know how to convert strings to integers where desired? What part of this do you need help with?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel karl I know how to read the lines seperately in .txt.I know the read outputs are coming in the form of string.But I do not know to convert and to assign them to relevant variables seperately

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45120726/how-to-read-csv-file-lines-and-split-elements-in-line-into-list-of-lists help?

Comment: Please show your code and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel looks different

Comment: @rpoleski code as follows.file1 = open("a.txt","r"),llines=file1.readline(),var1=[int(lines[0])] error as follows...ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3,0\n'

Answer (score 0):

You have to split line into words before applying `int()`

```py
with open("a.txt") as in_data:
    var1 = [int(word) for word in in_data.readline().split(",")]
    var2 = [int(word) for word in in_data.readline().split(",")]
    var3 = in_data.readline().split(",")
```